# How to integrate rankmath (WP SEO) tool with Nextjs 13 SEO?

Tags: wordpress, next.js, seo, next.js13

I want to integrate rank math SEO tool API support for SEO.

[Following this tutorial](https://rankmath.com/kb/headless-cms-support/), returns full HTML ready head with good metadata and others, but the problem is, how to render it into NextJS 13 head area?

Nextjs 13 not working more with the [Head](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/head) component/tag.

How do you even render those tags as HTML?

Have a nice day.

Comment: I'd recommend a read through https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package to parse string into html.

Package: `html-react-parser`

```
import parse from "html-react-parser";

function MyPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My Title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="My description" />
        {parse(post.head)}
      </Head>
      <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This won't work for nextjs 13 app directory.